# issue trying to save utf-8 in laravel

Tags: php, csv, laravel, laravel-4, utf-8

In my laravel app, I am working on a controller with two functions for adding users to the database (superfluous code excluded).

The first function takes input from a form and creates a single user:

```
public function addSingleUser() {
    $first_name = Input::get('firstName');
    $last_name  = Input::get('lastName');
    $email      = Input::get('email');
    $password   = str_random(6);

    $user = new User();
    $user->first_name = $first_name;
    $user->last_name  = $last_name;
    $user->email      = $email;
    $user->password   = Hash::make($password);
    $user->save();
}
```

The second function reads in data from a csv and creates multiple users:

```
public function addManyUsers() {
    putenv("LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8");
    $users = Input::file('users');
    $file = fopen($users,"r");

    while($info = fgetcsv($file, 4096)) {
        $first_name = trim($info[0]);
        $last_name = trim($info[1]);
        $email = trim($info[2]);
        $password   = str_random(6);

        $user = new User();
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->last_name = $last_name;
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
        $user->save();
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

Since users' names can have special characters, I need to be able to store utf-8 characters in the database. If I use utf-8 characters in the first function (via form input), everything gets stored correctly in the users table. But, if I use utf-8 characters in the second function (via csv), the fields are not stored correctly and get truncated at the first special character (ex: "Michæl" is stored as "Mich").

I thought this might be a problem with fgetscsv() not reading the data in correctly, but when I tried data-dumping a field (ex: `dd($first_name);`), the outputted string is correct, containing the special characters. The same is true if I try `dd($user);`. So if the first function is able to save correctly to the database, I am confused on why the second is not?

Comment: Did you try opening your csv file in an editor and saving it with UTF-8 encoding ? Briefly, did you try encoding the csv itself?

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu Saving with UTF-8 encoding worked. Sorry if this is a dumb question but why does that fix it? Thanks so much for you help.

Comment: I don't think this is a dumb question since everybody passes through this at least once. I think you will get the idea if you check the UTF-8 part here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Cool I will check that out. If you want, post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Why not? Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try opening your csv file in an editor and saving it with UTF-8 encoding ? Briefly, did you try encoding the csv itself?

Check UTF-8 part of [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for more information.

Best,